# Recursive tag search for Autocomplete - jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using the jQuery [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) plugin to search for tags in a textarea.

It's work perfectly, but now I need it search again while user is typing in the text box.

For example, I have:

```
var tags = [ 
        { label: "#schedules", value: "Monday, Wednesday and Friday from 9:00 p.m. to 6:00 p.m." }, 
        { label: "@address", value: "Some Address, 12345 - Some City" },
    ];

$("#text_box").autocomplete({

        source: function(request, response) {

            var matcher = new RegExp(
                "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i"
            );

            response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
                return matcher.test(item.label);
            }));

        }

    });
```

So if the user write:

"Hello, tanks for contact us, where be able #schedules you can find us in @address"

*the plugin must search all the coincidences again and suggest them on the bottom the text box every time. And the restultant string in the text box must be:*

"Hello, tanks for contact us, where be able Monday, Wednesday and Friday from 9:00 p.m. to 6:00 p.m. you can find us in Some Address, 12345 - Some City"

**Question:** How I can do this? Can the plugin do this, or I need to create my own algorithm?

Comment: I would suggest you review http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple demo. You will want to review each word as it's typed. Instead of being separated by `";"`, it will be separated by `"  "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, with some minor changes to the Demo, you can make a quick substitution menu.

```js
var tags = [{
  label: "@schedules",
  value: "Monday, Wednesday and Friday from 9:00 p.m. to 6:00 p.m."
}, {
  label: "@address",
  value: "Some Address, 12345 - Some City"
}];

$(function() {
  function split(val) {
    return val.split(" ");
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }
  $("#text_box").on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function(request, response) {
        var q = extractLast(request.term);
        console.log("Term: " + q);
        if (q.indexOf("@") == 0) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, q));
        }
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(" ");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#text_box {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<textarea id="text_box"></textarea>
```

**Update**

If you suspect that you will have multiple symbols, you could make use of a `switch()` statement or a complex `if()`. Something like:

```
if(q.indexOf("@") == 0 || q.indexOf("$") == 0 || q.indexOf("#") == 0){
  response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, q));
}
```

Or:

```
switch(true){
  case (q.term.indexOf("@") == 0):
  case (q.term.indexOf("$") == 0):
  case (q.term.indexOf("#") == 0):
    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, q));
    break;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention something very important: The initial symbol of the tag can be any, not always is the same.

Comment: Is it normal always appear a load animation inside the textarea and that never disappear?

Comment: @emi No that's not normal. Also I am not sure what you mean by 'can be any, not always the same' in your comment.

Comment: Can be like @aaa, $bbb, #ccc or any other symbol at the beginning of the label.

Comment: @emi the more initial symbols you have, the more difficult or more code you will have to implement to look for those various symbols.